# Inserting the values of variables in MYSQL in C

Tags: mysql, c

```
if(mysql_query(conn,"INSERT INTO Contacts VALUES('ABC','DEF','ABC',12345,6789,'123@gmail.com','456@gmail.com','India','Asia','21')"))
{
     printf("Inserted");
}
```

I want to insert the values stored in a variables into the table instead of directly entering the values. If anybody know please say how to do this.

Comment: The best way to do this is using parameterized queries or prepared statements. The worst way is using string manipulation on the query string, which will open up huge security issues. However, because you seem to have no clue on how to do any of this, I would say these topics are far too advanced for your current skill level.

Comment: I am new to C..Now whats the way to do this??